# SoapUI Loop through TestCases and log test case custom property

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I have a groovy script that loops through each test step, in each test case, in each test suite in the project. Each test case in the project has two custom properties assigned it is, `Test_Case_Response_Time` and `Test_Case_Response_Size`. I am trying to get it so that when it loops through each test case it log.info those two custom property for each test case.

Groovy Script:

```
//Loop thru the suites, followed by cases in each suite
suites.each 
{ suite ->
    //For each test SUITE perform the following action
    //------------------------------------------------  
    def tSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName(suite)
    tSuite.testCaseList.each 
    { kase ->
        //For each test CASE perform the following action
        //-----------------------------------------------       
        kase.testStepList.each 
        {
            //For each test step perform the following action
            //-----------------------------------------------       
            if(it.metaClass.hasProperty(it,'assertionStatus')){
                def assertions = it.getAssertionList()
                assertions.each
                { assertion ->
                    if(it.assertionStatus == AssertionStatus.VALID)
                    {
                    PassedTestCase += 1
                    }
                    else if(it.assertionStatus == AssertionStatus.FAILED)
                    {
                    FailedTestCase += 1
                    }
                }
            }
            //-----------------------------------------------

        }
        log.info testRunner.testCase["Test_Case_00: Setup"].getPropertyValue("Test_Case_Response_Time")
        log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("Test_Case_00: Setup").getPropertyValue("Test_Case_Response_Time")
        //-----------------------------------------------

    } 
    //-----------------------------------------------

}
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
log.info testRunner.testCase[kase.name].getPropertyValue("Test_Case_Response_Time")
log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName(kase.name).getPropertyValue("Test_Case_Response_Time")
```

The first line give me the following

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Test_Case_00:
>   Setup for class: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase
>   error at line: 37

and the second line gives me the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method
>   getPropertyValue() on null object error at line:37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I was looking in the wrong Test Suite. Using the following i was able to get it to find the correct properties:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName(suite).getTestCaseByName(kase.name).getPropertyValue("Test_Case_Response_Time")
```

Answer (score 0):

The below statement is not correct as **testCase[kase.name]** gives you property of testcase and not testcase itself

System is trying to search a property with the name"Test_Case_00: Setup" and hence giving error "No such property: Test_Case_00: Setup"

```
log.info testRunner.testCase[kase.name].getPropertyValue("Test_Case_Response_Time")
```

I was able to run the below code

```
log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName(kase.name).getPropertyValue("Test_Case_Response_Time")
```

In your actual code you have used the below line instead of kase.name

```
getTestCaseByName("**Test_Case_00: Setup**")
```

Looks like, **testcase** name is wrong, please copy the exact name and paste and it will work.

Below code worked for me. Its your code only.

```
    def tSuite = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite") // modified to run
tSuite.testCaseList.each 
{ kase ->
    //For each test CASE perform the following action
    //-----------------------------------------------       
    kase.testStepList.each 
    {
        //For each test step perform the following action
        //-----------------------------------------------       

    }
        //-----------------------------------------------
    // log.info kase.name

    // log.info testRunner.testCase[kase.name].getPropertyValue("Test_Case_Response_Time")  <-- wrong syntax
    log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName(kase.name).getPropertyValue("Test_Case_Response_Time")
 }
```

Comment: When i just use `log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName(kase.name).getPropertyValue("Test_Case_Response_Time")` I get the following error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getPropertyValue() on null object error at line:37`

Comment: There could be 2 reason.. Try to just print-->  log.info kase.name check if this works... Also then try log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName(kase.name). because in your case this is evaluating to null. Also make sure you have place this statement within the scope where kase variable is available. because the above code worked for me..